# When using `ui-bootstrap` for Angular, how do I load content for tabs from mark-up?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

In **regular bootstrap**, we do something similar to the code below -- where `href` references the `div id` to get the contents from.  How do we do it for **ui-bootstrap**?

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @azium, your link only says "Hello Plunkr"

Comment: Sorry, this I mean http://plnkr.co/edit/ffYg0avuMg2tRqDmnvwW?p=preview  This is straight from the docs https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs